# Not able to Call C++ method in C#

Tags: c#, c++

In my C# project I have to include a C++ library.

I have two methods in my C++ library as below:

```
APICLIENT_API std::map<std::string, std::string> logInWithParams(const char* url, const char* loginID, const char* password, const char* salt, const char* timeStamp, const char* refererURL, int iterations);


static APICLIENT_API int logIn(int iterations);
```

I am able to access the **logIn** method with below implementation in C#:

```
 [DllImport(@"F:\MySp\MySp\bin\APIClient.dll", EntryPoint = "?logIn@CAPIClient@API@@SAHH@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

public static extern int logIn(int g);
```

But unable to call **logInWithParams** method by any mean. Below is what I have tried.

```
 [DllImport(@"F:\MySp\MySp\bin\APIClient.dll", EntryPoint = "?logInWithParams@CAPIClient@API@@SA?AV?$map@V@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> logInWithParams([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string a, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string b, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string c, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string d, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string e, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string f, int g);
```

C# Implementaion:

```
 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> strMe = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    strMe = APICaller.logInWithParams("https://api.net/api/0.1/session/login", "james@Golmaal.com", "123123", "", "1403762225", "https://api.mini.net/", 4096);
```

**ERROR**:Cannot marshal 'return value': Generic types cannot be marshaled.

I have not written the C++ code , I just have to include it in my C# project.
I am new in integrating C++ library in C#. Kindly help in resolving this issue.

Comment: How do you expect C++ to know what `Dictionary<string, string>` is? You will probably have to use `C++/CLI` for this.

Comment: Use C++/CLI to map the `std::map` to the `Generic.Dictionary` data type you required. C# doesn't understand C++ library objects. Alternatively, you could break out the `map` into "raw" memory of some sort and then import the function.

Answer (score 1):

The marshaler doesn't convert C++ STL types to .NET types automatically.
You can create a managed C++ project where you are able to access that function and make the conversion manually there.
[See this example on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531624(v=vs.100).aspx)